# Creating responsive hyperlink link in Winform DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, hyperlink

I have Winform written in C#.

Specifically, I have a `DataGridView` control that looks like this:

```
No.|Description   | Quantity|   file                  | 
 1 |Beaker        |    2    |c:\PDF\Beaker.pdf        |
 2 |Conical Flask |    21   |c:\PDF\Conical Flask.pdf |
```

I want the **file** column to contain a hyperlink or a button that when clicked opens the PDF file on the user's machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, what you want to use is a DataGridViewLinkColumn.

Then, simply handle the DataGridView.CellContentClicked event.

From within the handler, you can have access to the cell content like so:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

...

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 3 && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Process.Start(filename);
        }

    }
```

Cheers

Comment: First I want to thank you for reply...
Instead of opening the message box, I want to open the desired file, which is a pdf file by program favored by user

Comment: You had not specified which part of the problem you specifically needed help with, so I assumed only the link column part. I updated my sample code to suit your needs.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, when the link clicked opens the file by program favored by user .
I can`t thank you enough you saved me the time and effort I have spent the past two days searching for this solution thank you very much

Comment: now when the link clicked opens the pdf file, but is a textboxcolmn not hyperlink or button how to do it .

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new question since you already marked this one as answered.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you need to make use of the `DataGridViewLinkColumn` and then handle the `DataGridView`'s `CellContentClick` event.

Here is how you would accomplish that:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn)
    {
        Process.Start(this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It's important that you register the event. Otherwise, the event handler code will never fire.

```
this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += 
       new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(
       this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
```

If for some reason a button was a preferable option for you, then you would need to make use of the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` in a similar fashion.